# Parsing JSON API result and loading in to Leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to take the JSON from an API call, parse it in to a GeoJSON array (just taking the lat, long and name variable) and then load it in to a Leaflet map.

I am getting no errors in the console. The geojson is loading in to the map but it is empty. When i query it (console.log(geojson) it appears empty. For some reason my function is failing to correctly parse in to the geojson.

```
var map1 = L.map('map').setView([52.599043, -1.325812], 6);

var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map1);


var ports = $.ajax({
          url:"API_URL",
          dataType: "json",
          success: console.log("County data successfully loaded."),
        })
var geojson = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: [],
};

for (var i in ports.data) {
  geojson.features.push({
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [ports.data[i].longitude, ports.data[i].latitude]
    },
    "properties": {
      "stationName": ports.data[i].port_name
    }
  });
}

L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map1);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Does this mean that I would have to find a way to wait for the Ajax call to finish loading before running the rest of the code?

Comment: That's the gist of asynchronous functions (do something in the "background" and come back when ready) and very well explained in the accepted answer (and its first link) of the duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Andreas's comment I looked in to Asynchronous AJAX.

I ended up restructuring my code to ensure that the processing of the response was done after the ajax call was completed:

I nested the processing of API response in a function that used the output from the API call. The API call has a function that runs when it's successful that passes the response to the processing function.

```
function callback1(response) {
    var geojson = {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: [],
        };

    for (var i in response.data) {
        geojson.features.push({
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [response.data[i].longitude, response.data[i].latitude]
        },
        "properties": {
        "stationName": response.data[i].port_name
        }
        })};
        L.geoJSON(geojson, {onEachFeature:Ports_Popup}).addTo(map1);
        console.log(response);
};

$.ajax({
      url:"https://statistics-api.dft.gov.uk/api/ports?filter[country]=scotland",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response){
      callback1(response)
    }})
```

Comment: Good job in learning JavaScript asynchronicity! Nice to share your results here. Keep up the good work.